# X session lost after some idle time with screen locked

Tags: lock-screen, session

When taking a break from working in my laptop (Xubuntu 14.10), I always lock the screen on my pc, keeping many applications running. Usually all is normal, regardless of the idle time I take. However, this is the second time that I lose my session after an idle time with the X session locked. It happens like this: when I return to my station, I log in, and then, after a few weird flashes, it goes back to the main log in screen again (just like if I had restarted the computer, which is not what is happening by the way because I have a boot password that prevents the immediate run of the OS). When I enter my password again, a new session starts, (no previous application running). However, there is some memory as the browser remember my last tabs open and gmusicbrowser's queue list.

Both times that I have lost my session have been long idle times (more than one hour). *Apparently*, this only affects me if idle time is long. I tried to reproduce the problem by short idle times and I can't. I will try to reproduce it for lon idle times but that is not very handy.

Comment: I've had this problem now a couple times. Only started very recently (last month or so). Hard to reproduce, but I've also had it happen after short breaks. Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell XPS 13 laptop

Comment: I am about to upgrade to xfce 4.12. Maybe that is fixed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved when upgrading to 16.04. Screen has no single glitch either. All works fine. The open-source radeon driver works flawlessly!